# how to run a loop to values we have in array in C?

Tags: c

if array has size 5 and we have put only 2 or 3 integer values then how we could run a       loop till the values we entered in C?Actually i am making program in C where i need to run a loop till the number of elements we have in array?

```
 void main()
 { 
    char a[]="this is a man"; 
    int b[5],j=0,q; 
    int p= sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); 
    for(int i=0;i<=p;i++)
    { 
        if(a[i]=='i')
        { 
            b[j]=i; j++;
        }  
    } 

    for(int k=0;k<=5;k++)
    { 
        printf("value %d\n",b[k]); 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597830/iterate-through-a-c-array

Comment: ***Show Sample Code***, then we can improve on it, instead of just talking about hypotheticals.

Comment: @user2980181 In your loop you use `j` to count, right? Just use it when printing the array `b`. You don't need any magics.

Comment: thanks haccks..above is a code now tell me what do use in place of "k<=5".

Comment: I edited my answer. You can do this without any sentinel value. Read the answer.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i < p;i++)` for a start. and `int main(void)` of course

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029783/get-the-number-of-elements-that-it-has-a-value-in-array for my Ten Different Ways (in truth only 9, I'm still thinking of a tenth way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sentinel value such as `-1` or `0` at the end. Check for that sentinel on each iteration to come out from the loop.

```
int a[5];  

while(a[i] != -1)  
{
     ...
}
```

EDIT: Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[]="this is a man";
    int b[5] = {0};    //I initialized all elements of b to 0.
    int j=0;
    int p= sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    for(int i=0;i<p;i++)  // I used i < p instead of yours i <= p.
    {
        if(a[i]=='i')
        {
            b[j]=i; j++;
        }
    }

    for(int k=0;k<5;k++)  // k < 5 instead of k <= 5.
    {
        if(b[k])            //Check for the non zero value of b, if yes print that value.
            printf("value %d\n",b[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: its a good suggestion..but problem is that other values are also non zero like "8653" 9103"..

Comment: thanks buddy...please let me know how u found that?/

Comment: Care fully read this answer. In this answer I changed many things but most important for your program is I remove `=` from both of your loop which is causing your programs behavior undefined and printing `8653`, `9103` as garbage values.

Comment: thanks a lot..next time i'll more careful about all these things..thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. I glad that my answer helped you :)

Comment: haccks if u r still there..i want to ask something  from u..please reply..

Comment: @user2980181; *thanks buddy...please let me know how u found that?*: By answering couples of question on SO almost everyday :)

Comment: Yes. I am here. Go ahead.

Comment: if i delete the all the elements of which i got the position..there is a problem.when we delete one element and move very next element to its place.the next position we got delete the element previous to the position we want..

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Please rephrase your words or give some example what you want to do..

Comment: i don't have that much repo..to continue comment so long and i can't chat as my repo is low.do u have any other option..well i'll place a code in comment.i don't know how to place it properly here.but i'll try

Comment: for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
  {
    if(b[k]) {
    printf("value %d\n",b[k]);
    for(int c=b[k];c<p;c++)
    a[c]=a[c+1];

    }

  }
  printf("values of array %s",a);

Comment: the problem is here that first time it deletes correct word but after that it deletes character before the position we mentioned and so on...

Comment: OK. I understand. You want the output `ths s a man`, right? Let me check.

Comment: Define `int count = 0`. Then do this `for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
 {
  if(b[k])
  {
   printf("value %d\n",b[k]);

   for(int c = b[k] - count; c < p - 1; c++)
   {
    a[c]=a[c + 1];
    
   }
   count++;
   
  }
 }`

Comment: well tell me way to increase my repo..so i could chat with people like u??

Comment: Yes you can. Ask some good questions but before asking search SO whether it is asked already on SO. Also you can answer some questions if you know the answer. The easiest way to get reputation is edit the questions and answers such as, spelling mistake, grammatical mistakes or code indentation etc. You will get `2` reputation for each edit. :). Read the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) for detailed information.

Comment: thanks..i'll try.well your language of interest is??

Comment: NO..i am asking about programming language..well for me its English and Hindi..

Comment: i do want to learn web technologies..i hope u'll help me in it as well..well i am basically involved in android.but nowdays working on C,C++ to understand pointers well..

Comment: Best of luck. Keep in touch with Stack Overflow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42568/discussion-between-user2980181-and-haccks)

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the array with some known placeholder value and check for that placeholder value while iterating each element.