# Operator overload "<" declared in Swift class is sometimes not called when used in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, operator-overloading, language-interoperability

I've come across a strange issue related to Swift/Objective-C interoperability. The case is this:

I have an `@objc public class GKDistance:NSObject,NSCoding,Comparable` written in Swift. In order to compare distances, I have added an operator overload for `<` as follows:

```
public func <(a:GKDistance, b:GKDistance) -> Bool {
    return a.value < b.value
}

public func ==(a:GKDistance, b:GKDistance) -> Bool {
    return a.value == b.value
}
```

It's then used in an Objective-C method like so:

```
if (distance < averageDistance){
    // code
}
```

When the Objective-C method is called I can add a `print()` statement and breakpoint in the `<` method to confirm when the operator overload is being used. In one case, *it mysteriously skips the operator overload defined in Swift*, and uses the regular Objective-C comparator between two GKDistance objects.

When run with `distance.value == 2375.1842554877021` and `averageDistance.value == 75.671794891357421`, `distance < averageDistance` returns `true`, the Swift operator overload is never hit, and Objective-C executes the code inside the conditional.

If I convert the Objective-C method in question to Swift, it behaves as expected, but I'm concerned that there are other GKDistance comparisons in various Objective-C methods throughout our app that could be failing to see the Swift operator overload.

Has anyone run into similar issues with Swift/Objective-C interoperability as it pertains to operator overloading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your

```
public func <(a:GKDistance, b:GKDistance) -> Bool { }
```

is – like all Swift operators – 
a *top-level function,* and top-level functions
are not exported to Objective-C, see "Swift Type Compatibility"
in ["Interacting with Objective-C APIs"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35).

Also note that you *cannot* override operators (like `<`) in (Objective-)C, see e.g.

- [Operator overloading in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417413/operator-overloading-in-c)
- [Is it possible to overload operators in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624525/is-it-possible-to-overload-operators-in-c)

Therefore in

```
if (distance < averageDistance) {
    // code
}
```

just the two *pointers* are compared, and the condition is true if
the object pointed to by `distance` resides in a lower memory address
than the object pointer to by `averageDistance` (which is obviously
not what you intended).

What you could do is to implement a `compare:` method in your class,
similar to the one of `NSString` or `NSNumber`.

Note also that for `NSObject` subclasses, you should override
`isEqual:` instead of implementing `==`, compare

- [NSObject subclass in Swift: hash vs hashValue, isEqual vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319959/nsobject-subclass-in-swift-hash-vs-hashvalue-isequal-vs)

Comment: I don't think you have answered the question.  While I understand that you cannot overload operators (like <) in Objective-C, the question is ... when you overload an operator in Swift, then call that function from the ObjC to Swift bridge can Objective C use the (very legal) operator overload in Swift.  Also, can you point to any documentation justifying your position?

Comment: @ColinPhillips:  `if (distance < averageDistance)` does not call any function, and the `<` operator is "built-in" in C, compare e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417413/operator-overloading-in-c. That are two pointers, and they are compared.

Comment: @ColinPhillips: I have added some references.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Operator overloads specified in Swift classes will NOT be accessible to Objective-C, and the Objective-C code will compare pointers 100% of the time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @MartinR - I have up-voted your answer.